# What does the word 'ray' in the math mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In some PDE books, ray is always used. For example, solve the PDE in the ray $x>0$. What does the ray means? points $(x,y)$ where $x$ is greater than zero?

Comment: I think it means "half-line".

Comment: A ray is a line with an endpoint, like sun rays.

Comment: A ray is like a line except that rather than continuing indefinitely in both directions it only continues indefinitely in one direction and originates from a point.  It is most common to consider rays originating from the origin, though that is not required.  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#Ray).

Comment: A line may be described parametrically by a point on the line and its direction, e.g. as $\{\vec{P}+\vec{D}t~:~t\in\Bbb R\}$ where the parameter $t$ may be any real positive or otherwise.  A ray on the other hand the parameter will be restricted to non-negative values only: $\{\vec{P}+\vec{D}t~:~t\in\Bbb R^+\}$

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the most basic topics of geometry . You have $3$ times of $1$-dimensional figures :- A **line**, A **line-segment** and A **ray** .

$(i)$ A line is a set of points in a straight path that extends in opposite directions infinitely .

$(ii)$ A line-segment is a part of a line which has a definite length and has $2$ endpoints .

$(iii)$ A ray is a part of a line that has $1$ endpoint and extends infinitely in $1$ direction .

We denote lines by $2$ arrows , rays with $1$ arrow and $1$ point , and line segments with $2$ points respectively .

Here is a figure to understand :-

[image]